# get Product not work - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, object-manager, print

I'm trying to create a php file to be inserted in my Magento root that prints all the products and the associated fields.

```
    <?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}  

?>
```

I found this that should print all the product names but give me this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager' not found in ../../public_html/folder/file.php on line 3
```

The error is over

> $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

Help for pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create `test.php` in your root directory and paste below code and run from browser `http://your base url/test.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
try {
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
     exit;
}  
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::create() in /public_html/test.php on line 18